# Android AlarmManager is cancelling alarm when app is dead after fresh install of app on device

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have made an alarm clock app that uses `AlarmManager` to place alarms. There is a broadcast receiver that receives the alarm broadcast, and then starts a foreground service.

Consider this situation: I do a fresh installation of my app on a device and add an alarm. I let a few seconds pass by, open a terminal window, and type the following command: `adb shell dumpsys alarm`. In the list, I **can** find the alarm registered by my app.

Now, I close the app (clear it from recents), make sure the alarm process is dead from Android Studio logcat, and again type the above command. I **cannot** find my alarm in the list! The alarm was there just a few seconds back, and now it is not there.

So I open the app again, delete this alarm, and add another alarm. With `dumpsys`, I can find my alarm in the list. I close my app and again execute `dumpsys`, only to find that this time, my alarm **is** there in the list. When the time arrives, the foreground service starts properly.

Why is the alarm getting cancelled after I close the app in case of a fresh installation?

Comment: I think it is expected behaviour..please refer below links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392824/alarmmanager-pendingintent-gone-after-swiping-app-from-recent-apps-on-some-devi/41492023?noredirect=1 .  https://github.com/evernote/android-job/issues/128

Comment: @Dilip that's irritating. Any workaround you know of?